# SingleDivUI: Simple Chart library with CSS

Tags: javascript, css, library

I have created a [SingleDivUI](https://singledivui.com/) chart library with CSS.

Here the idea is to create the UI components with a single div element by CSS. To explore the power of CSS and to bring some innovative thoughts I started to reserch on this, finally I can make the fully usable Chart component with a lot of customization.

Here is the repository of the Source code:
https://github.com/soundar24/SingleDivUI

Since I have multiple files here, so I outlined the files details so that it can be referred from the repo directly.

[Src](https://github.com/soundar24/SingleDivUI/tree/master/src)

- [Base](https://github.com/soundar24/SingleDivUI/tree/master/src/Base)

  - [dom-utill.js](https://github.com/soundar24/SingleDivUI/blob/master/src/Base/dom-utill.js)

    *(contains the DOM interaction related utility functions)*
  - [util.js](https://github.com/soundar24/SingleDivUI/blob/master/src/Base/util.js)

    *(contains some common utility functions)*
- [Chart](https://github.com/soundar24/SingleDivUI/tree/master/src/Chart)

  - [styles](https://github.com/soundar24/SingleDivUI/tree/master/src/Chart/styles)

    *(contains the CSS styles related to the Chart)*
  - [area.js](https://github.com/soundar24/SingleDivUI/blob/master/src/Chart/area.js)

    *(since area chart inherited from line chart, so internally call this)*
  - [bar.js](https://github.com/soundar24/SingleDivUI/blob/master/src/Chart/bar.js)

    *(bar chart related logic and styles generation)*
  - [chart.js](https://github.com/soundar24/SingleDivUI/blob/master/src/Chart/chart.js)

    *(actual Chart component class, contains the default props and initialization logic with other component related logic)*
  - [graph.js](https://github.com/soundar24/SingleDivUI/blob/master/src/Chart/graph.js)

    *(chart's graph related logic and it's styles generation)*
  - [line.js](https://github.com/soundar24/SingleDivUI/blob/master/src/Chart/line.js)

    *(line chart related logic and styles generation)*
  - [linear-scale.js](https://github.com/soundar24/SingleDivUI/blob/master/src/Chart/linear-scale.js)

    *(graph's Y-axis generation related logic)*
  - [series.js](https://github.com/soundar24/SingleDivUI/blob/master/src/Chart/series.js)

    *(Series class for initialize the corresponding chart type)*

#### **`chart.js`**

```js
import Graph from './graph';
import Series from './series';
import { deepExtend, throttle } from '../Base/util';
import { querySelector, addClass, removeClass, setWidth, setHeight, isDOM, injectStyles } from '../Base/dom-utill';

const PLUGIN_NAME = "SingleDivUI.Chart";
// class names
const CLASS_PREFIX = 'sd-';
const CLASS_CHART = CLASS_PREFIX + 'chart'; // sd-chart
const CLASS_GRAPH = CLASS_PREFIX + 'graph'; // sd-graph

Chart.prototype = {
    PLUGIN_NAME,
    version: "__VERSION__",

    // after the control initialization the updated default values
    // are merged into the options
    options: {},

    // holds the current Chart element
    control: null,

    styleEle: null,

    // default properties of the Chart plugin
    defaults: {
        // type should be 'line', 'bar' or 'area'
        type: null,
        data: {
            labels: [],
            
            series: {
                points: [],

                // ------ for line-chart related customizations ------
                lineColor: null,
                lineSize: null,
                pointRadius: null,
                pointColor: null,
                pointBorderWidth: null,
                pointBorderColor: null,
                pointStyle: null,
                pointInnerColor: null,
                dotRadius: null,

                // ------ for bar-chart related customizations ------
                barSize: null,
                barColor: null,

                // ------ for area-chart related customizations ------
                areaColor: null
            },
        },

        graphSettings: {
            labelFontSize: '11px',
            labelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial, sans-serif',
            gridLineColor: null,
            gridLineSize: null,
            axisLineColor: null,
            axisLineSize: null,
            labelColor: null,
            labelDistance: null,

            xAxis: {
                verticalLabel: false,
                padding: [0, 0],
                labelFormatter: null
            },
            yAxis: {
                maxTicks: 10,
                startFromZero: false,
                labelFormatter: null,

                customScale: {
                    min: null,
                    max: null,
                    interval: null
                }
            }
        },

        height: 260,
        width: '100%',
        responsive: true,

        stylesAppendTo: 'head'
    },
    
    _init: function () {
        this._initialize();
        this._render();
    },

    _initialize: function () {
        var chart = this.control;
        var { type, width, height, responsive } = this.options;

        // add the related class names to the root element
        var classNames = CLASS_CHART + ' ' + CLASS_GRAPH;
        if (type) {
            classNames += ' ' + CLASS_PREFIX + type;
        }
        this.rootClasses = addClass(chart, classNames);

        // set the dimensions of the control, based on the
        // height, width only all the callculations will happen
        setWidth(chart, width);
        setHeight(chart, height);

        // for response support
        if (responsive) {
            if (!this._tResizeFn) {
                this._tResizeFn = throttle(this._onResize, 300, this);
            }
            window.addEventListener('resize', this._tResizeFn);
        }
    },

    _render: function () {
        var chart = this.control;
        var options = this.options;
        var { type, data, graphSettings = {} } = options;
        var seriesObj = data.series;

        // TODO: as of now ignore the series type
        seriesObj.type = type;

        var chartHeight = chart.clientHeight;
        var chartWidth = this.chartWidth = chart.clientWidth;
        var xAxisData = data.labels;
        var yAxisData = seriesObj.points;

        // bar chart needs an additional column, since each bar renders in-between the column
        var needExtraColumn = (type === 'bar');

        // render the Graph
        var graph = new Graph(chartHeight, chartWidth, xAxisData, yAxisData, graphSettings, needExtraColumn);

        // render the Series
        var series = new Series(seriesObj, graph);

        // merge all the required styles with corresponding selectors
        var styles = this._generateStyles(graph, series, type);

        // inject the generated styles into DOM
        this.styleEle = injectStyles(styles, options.stylesAppendTo, this.styleEle, this.selector);
    },

    _generateStyles: function (graph, series, type) {
        var styles = {},
            selector = this.selector + '.',
            graphStyles = graph.styles,
            seriesStyles = series.styles;
        
        var graph_selector = selector + CLASS_GRAPH,
            graphX_selector = graph_selector + ':after',
            graphY_selector = graph_selector + ':before',
            series_selector = selector + CLASS_PREFIX + type;

        styles[graph_selector] = graphStyles.common;
        styles[graphX_selector] = graphStyles.x;
        styles[graphY_selector] = graphStyles.y;
        if (seriesStyles) {
            styles[series_selector] = seriesStyles;
        }

        return styles;
    },

    _onResize: function () {
        var chart = this.control;
        if (this.chartWidth !== chart.clientWidth) {
            this.refresh();
        }
    },

    // public methods
    update: function (options) {
        deepExtend(this.options, options);
        this.refresh();
    },
    refresh: function () {
        this._clearAll();
        this._init();
    },
    destroy: function () {
        this._clearAll(true);
    },

    // private methods
    _clearAll: function (destroy) {
        var chart = this.control;

        // remove all the chart related classes that added initially
        removeClass(chart, this.rootClasses);

        // remove all the inline styles that added
        if (this.options.stylesAppendTo === 'inline') {
            chart.removeAttribute('style');
        }
        else {
            setWidth(chart, '', true);
            setHeight(chart, '', true);
        }

        // remove all the dynamic stylesheet that created
        var styleEle = this.styleEle;
        (styleEle || {}).innerHTML = '';

        // unbind the responsive related events
        if (this._tResizeFn) {
            window.removeEventListener('resize', this._tResizeFn);
        }

        // in case of destroy, completely remove the elements and instances
        if (destroy) {
            styleEle && styleEle.remove();
            this.styleEle = null;

            // remove the plugin instance that saved on the element
            delete chart[PLUGIN_NAME];
        }
    }
};

// The plugin constructor
function Chart(selector, options) {
    var control = selector, strSelector = '';
    if (typeof selector === 'string') {
        control = querySelector(selector);
        strSelector = selector;
    }
    if (!isDOM(control)) {
        console.error(PLUGIN_NAME + `: Element(${selector}) is not available!`);
        return;
    }

    // try to get the chart instance from the elment
    // to confirm whether the chart already got initialized
    var instance = control[PLUGIN_NAME];
    if (instance) {
        instance.update(options);
        return instance;
    }

    if (!strSelector) {
        var id = control.id;
        strSelector = id ? '#' + id : '';
    }

    this.control = control;
    this.selector = strSelector;
    // save the instance on the element for the future reference
    control[PLUGIN_NAME] = this;

    // the options value holds the updated defaults value
    this.options = deepExtend({}, this.defaults);
    deepExtend(this.options, options);

    this._init();
}

export default Chart;
```

Also suggest me any best practices that I missed any.

Thanks for your time!